# Munit in Jenkins with dependency on Domain projects

Tags: maven, jenkins, mule, munit

I have Mule Project "A" which refers a Domain Project "X". I would like to run my MUnits for Project "A" in Jenkins but it fails as it's unable to find the dependency Domain project "X".
To resolve this I added the "dependency" for domain project"A" in, project "X" pom. xml. But no luck.

Please give me details how it can be resolved to run my MUnits ion Jenkins as a post-build action.

Thanks,
Ikram

Answer (score 0):

to be able to do that I had to:

- First, add the domain dependency in your pom with "test" scope

  > ```
  > <dependency>
  >      <groupId>com.mygroupid</groupId>
  >      <artifactId>mule-domain-id</artifactId>
  >      <version>1.0.0</version>
  >      <scope>test</scope>
  >      <type>zip</type>
  > </dependency>
  > ```
- Second, you have to install the domain artifact in one artifact repository (Nexus for example).This way, the dependency is accessible from Jenkins. And then add that repository to your pom.xml

  > ```
  > <repositories>
  >   <repository>
  >     <id>alm-nexus</id>
  >     <name>ALM Nexus Repo</name>
  >     <url>https://nexus.alm.corp/repository/maven-public</url>
  >     <layout>default</layout>
  >   </repository>
  > </repositories>
  > ```
- One important thing when runing MUnits in Jenkins is the following. The root folder name has to be exactly the same as the artifactId, so in Jenkins you have to set the workspace with a custom one
  If using a Jenkinsfile you can do this with the following:

  > customWorkspace
  >   "${env.JOB_NAME}/${env.BUILD_ID}/artifact-id-has-to-go-here"

With these steps we are able to have a working pipeline with MUnit testing as one of the stages.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will try this approach

Comment: Perfect, if this works for you please mark the answer as correct.Thx

Comment: Hi Ikram, any feedback about the proposed solution?